# QTreeWidget contactos en C++, con QT y XMPP

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy intento hacer una lista con todos mis contactos que tenga en mi cuenta. Para ello mostrare los que estan conectados y no. Me baso en el protocolo de comunicación de chat XMPP. 
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
    void MainWindow::rosterRecibido()
{
    logado = true; //cuando recibimos el roster ya mostramos el frame con la lista de conectados
    ui->frameLogin->hide();
    ui->frameConexion->show();
    int i,j;
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    QStringList contactos = cliente.rosterManager().getRosterBareJids();
    for(i=0;i<contactos.length();i++)
    {
        item->setText(0,contactos[i]);
        QStringList recursos = cliente.rosterManager().getResources(contactos[i]);
        QIcon online;
        online.addFile(":/icons/user-offline.png");
        item->setIcon(0,online);
        for(j=0;j<recursos.length();j++)
        {
            item->addChild(new QTreeWidgetItem());
            item->child(j)->setText(0,recursos[j]);
            online.addFile(":/icons/user-online.png");
            item->setIcon(0,online);
            item->child(j)->setIcon(0,online);
            listaItems.append(item);

        }


    }
    ui->arbolConectados->addTopLevelItems(listaItems);
}
```

Lo que me pasa que cuando agrego un contacto el anterior es borrado a pesar de que lo añado a lista. Repito es basado en el sistema XMPP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás reutilizando el mismo item. Cada item del árbol debe ser un objeto de tipo `QTreeWidgetItem` independiente. Entiendo que la declaración:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
```

debería ir dentro del bucle `for`.

Por cierto, los paréntesis no son necesarios en la sintáxis del `new`:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem;
```